# How to use apple's new type of "clear" background in Xcode

Tags: xcode, background

In the new ios14 and macOS Big Sur, Apple is using a type of "clear" background (also, in NavigationView, when scrolling, this same type of background is used). How do I use them? Tried using opacity but the result is different

[[image: 12]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to this tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ew_99X-DQI4), I was able to do it.

First, I created this struct:

```
struct BlurView: UIViewRepresentable {

func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIVisualEffectView {
    
    let view = UIVisualEffectView(effect: UIBlurEffect(style: .systemChromeMaterial))
    
    return view
}

func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIVisualEffectView, context: Context) {
    
    
}
}
```

Then, just added `.background(BlurView())`